# Trouble in parsing French characters from an url

Tags: android, json

I tried to get the JSON response from an URL. I used the following code. The response contains french characters. In browser the response is fine, it shows the characters correctly. When I use it in app, the characters looks different, for example like this  "terminal_key": "cl� Terminal".

```
InputStream is = null;
                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://ptracker.com/webteh/localization.php");

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();          

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String json = null;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                    Log.v("json >>",json);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your logcat....Does it show the same response or it shows the right characters?

Comment: Then I think you should do some parsing at the web server side such as replace '&#163;' with '£'